# SQL Server Selecting DISTINCT record to string variable

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I want to select all distinct name from person table to `VARCHAR` variable .
I have write a query that returns all name as follow.

```
DECLARE @pName as VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @pName=''

SELECT @pName += RTRIM(FullName) + ',' 
FROM Persons 

SELECT @pName
```

When I try to select distinct on `FullName`, SQL Server throws an exception.

```
DECLARE @pName as VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @pName=''

SELECT DISTINCT FullName, @pName += RTRIM(FullName) + ',' 
FROM Persons 

SELECT @pName
```

> Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Distinct on variable name return only first Name

```
SELECT DISTINCT @pName += RTRIM(FullName) +
FROM Persons 

SELECT @pName
```

How can I select distinct name to string variable from `SELECT` statement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sql Server version?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same distinct result without using the variable also.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + FullName FROM Persons
              FOR xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '')
```

Using variable - Add a `group By`

```
DECLARE @pName as VARCHAR(MAX)
set @pName=''
SELECT    @pName+= RTRIM(FullName) + ',' FROM Persons Group By FullName
select @pName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @pName as VARCHAR(MAX)
with cte as(
SELECT DISTINCT FullName FROM Persons
) 
Select @pName = coalesce(@pName + ', ', '') + FullName 
from cte

select @pName
```